# How to generate rows in BigQuery by geometrical sequence?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to generate rows in BigQuery table using geometrical sequence.
For example I have rows with first term and limit.
I want to populate each row with values equals all terms of sequence less then limit.
Ratio is a constant.

Is it possible to make it in BigQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 2 term, 60 max_value, 3 ratio
)
SELECT term, max_value, ratio, 
  sequence_pos, 
  CAST(FLOOR(term * POWER(ratio, sequence_pos)) AS INT64) sequence_value, 
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, CAST(FLOOR(LOG(max_value/term) / LOG(ratio)) AS INT64))) sequence_pos
ORDER BY sequence_pos
```

with output

```
Row term    max_value   ratio   sequence_pos    sequence_value   
1   2       60          3       0               2    
2   2       60          3       1               6    
3   2       60          3       2               18   
4   2       60          3       3               54
```

Should be easy to extend above to whatever your real use case